# Using boost serialization with Windows Forms Application

Tags: c++, winforms, boost, clr

I've a problem with boost and the .net-Framework. I wrote my classes without .net. This project worked fine and now I include the class-files into a windows forms application. There occurred many compiler errors, something like "__declspec(dllexport) couldn't use with /clr:pure or /clr:safe" in singleton.hpp (a boost-library). I create an example.
In the Form1-header only this class is include and nothing else is done, just from Visual Studio 2010 generated code.

This is a test class, which I created to show you a simple case:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

class Foo
{
private:
    int  name;

public:
    void setName(int name);
    int getName(void);
private:
    friend boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize (Archive& arch, const unsigned int)
    {
        arch & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(this->name);
    }
};
#endif
```

I've try to switch the /clr:pure to /clr, with this the compiler could compile it, but while starting the program a mistake occured.  It is a titled with "Debug Assertion Failed!" in the exe-file. In the messagebox you can also read "Expression:_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)"
At the moment I use boost 1.52.0, but I also tried it with boost 1.53.0. I installed boost with "bootstrap.bat" and "bjam.exe".

Does someone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: You must use /clr, no pure.  Nobody could possibly guess what "a mistake occured" might mean.

Comment: @Hans Passant Oh sorry I thought this is not important. It is a "Debug Assertion Failed!" occured in the exe-file. In the messagebox you can also read "Expression:_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)"

Comment: Note that `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` makes element name from its argument, so the name would be "this->name". I'm not sure the xml parser is fine with "->". Use `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name)` instead or if it should be fully qualified, use a temporary local var.

Comment: @IgorR Thank you for this information, but this was just a simple example project. In the real project I doesn't use this, but I try it out. Back to the problem. The debug error was just a temporary one, now it doesn't occured. So using /clr seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Hans Passant've found the solution. I post the way for some who has the same problem and doesn't know how to change /clr. You must change /clr:pure to /clr. The mistake, which occured was just a temporary one. Now it works.

To chance the /clr:pure in Visual Studio (2010/2012) you must entered the Project-tab and click on Properties. There click to C/C++>>General and chance the "Common Language RunTime Support" from /clr:pure to /clr.